# initjvm.sql not found at $ORACLE_HOME/javam/install/initjvm.sql how do i install dbms_java package

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm try to install `dbms_java`

> initjvm.sql not found at $ORACLE_HOME/javam/install/initjvm.sql

How do I install `dbms_java` package?

Comment: it's $ORACLE_HOME/java**v**m/, not `$ORACLE_HOME/javam/` (note the missing v)

Comment: @sathya ya that folder only spell mistake